# LinkedList class cant access other classes

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a LinkedList class that cannot access my Student class methods for some reason. I dont understand why this would be happening due to my linkedlist class is of type Student. I keep receiving the error cannot find symbol symbol: method getName() Location: variable data of type Student where Student is a type-variable: Student extends Object declared in class node. The method below is from my linked list class

```
public double findGpa(String name){
    Node<Student> temp = head;
    double foundData = 0.0;
    for(int i = 1 ; (i < size); i++){
        if(temp.data.getName().equals(name)){
            foundData = temp.data.getGpa();
        }
        temp = getNode(i);
    }

    return foundData;
}
```

getGpa is a method in my Student class because the Node is of type student and data is also of type student I dont understand why it cant access the Student methods
My student class is listed below

```
package lab3;


public class Student {

    private String fullName;
    private double gpa;

    public Student(String name, double gpa){
        fullName = name;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public void setGpa(double grade){
        gpa = grade;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        fullName = name;
    }

    public double getGpa(){
        return gpa;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return fullName;
    }

}
```

Here is the Whole LinkedList class that has the Node Class as an inner class

```
package lab3;

/**
 *
 * @author Chris
 */
/**
 * SingleLinkedList is a class that provides some of the
 * capabilities required by the List interface using
 * a single linked list data structure.
 * Only the following methods are provided:
 * get, set, add, remove, size, toString
 * @author Koffman and Wolfgang 
 * @param <Student> 
 */
public class StudentSingleLinkedList<Student> {

    private static class Node<Student> {

        /** The data value. */
        private Node<Student> next;
        /** The link */
        private Student data;

        /**
         * Construct a node with the given data value and link
         * @param data - The data value
         * @param next - The link
         */
        public Node(Student d, Node<Student> next) {
            this.next = next;
            data = d;
        }

        /**
         * Construct a node with the given data value
         * @param data - The data value
         */
        public Node(Student d) {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    // Data fields
    /** A reference to the head of the list */
    private Node<Student> head = null;
    /** The size of the list */
    private int size = 0;


    // Helper Methods
    /** Insert an item as the first item of the list.
     *  @param item The item to be inserted
     */
    private void addLast(Student item){

        Node<Student> newNode = getNode(size);
        newNode.next = new Node<Student>(item, newNode.next);
        size++;

    }

    private void addFirst(Student item) {
        head = new Node<Student>(item, head);
        size++;
    }

    /**
     * Add a node after a given node
     * @param node The node which the new item is inserted after
     * @param item The item to insert
     */
    private void addAfter(Node<Student> node, Student item) {
        node.next = new Node<Student>(item, node.next);
        size++;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the first node from the list
     * @returns The removed node's data or null if the list is empty
     */
    private Student removeFirst() {
        Node<Student> temp = head;
        if (head != null) {
            head = head.next;
        }
        if (temp != null) {
            size--;
            return temp.data;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /*
    public double findGpa(String name){
        Node<Student
    }
    */


    private double findGpa(String name){
        Node<Student> temp = head;
        double foundData = 0.0;
        for(int i = 1 ; (i < size); i++){
            if(temp.data.getName().equals(name)){
                foundData = temp.data.getGpa();
            }
            temp = getNode(i);
        }

        return foundData;
    }


    public Student updateGpa(String name){
        Node<Student> temp = head;
        if(temp.next.equals(name)){
            temp.data =
        }
    }
    /**
     * Remove the node after a given node
     * @param node The node before the one to be removed
     * @returns The data from the removed node, or null
     *          if there is no node to remove
     */
    private Student removeAfter(Node<Student> node) {
        Node<Student> temp = node.next;
        if (temp != null) {
            node.next = temp.next;
            size--;
            return temp.data;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find the node at a specified index
     * @param index The index of the node sought
     * @returns The node at index or null if it does not exist
     * 
     * 
     */
    private Node<Student> getNode(int index){
        Node<Student> temp = head;
        if(temp == null){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++){
                temp = temp.next;
            }         
        }
        return temp;
    }

    // Public Methods
    /**
     * Get the data value at index
     * @param index The index of the element to return
     * @returns The data at index
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of range
     * 
     * 
     * Uses getNode() to access the nodes index then calls the .data to get 
     * whatever data is being stored inside that node.
     */
    public Student get(int index) {
       Node<Student> temp = getNode(index);
       if(temp== null){
           throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
       }

       return temp.data;

    }

    /**
     * Set the data value at index
     * @param index The index of the item to change
     * @param newValue The new value
     * @returns The data value previously at index
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of           
     *  range
     * 
     * 
     * Uses the getNode method to get the index of the node and replace it with
     * the data that temp holds
     */
    public Student set(int index, Student newValue) {
        if(head == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(index > size){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Node<Student> temp = getNode(index);
        Student temp2 = temp.data;
        temp.data = newValue;
        return temp2;

    }

    /**
     * Insert the specified item at the specified position in the list.
     * Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
     * subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indicies)
     * @param index Index at which the specified item is to be inserted
     * @param item The item to be inserted
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of range
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * If index is less than 0 and greater than the size throw an exception
     * If index is equal to 0 then item will be the first node
    /**
     * Insert the specified item at the specified position in the list.
     * Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
     * subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indicies)
     * @param index Index at which the specified item is to be inserted
     * @param item The item to be inserted
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of range
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * If index is less than 0 and greater than the size throw an exception
     * If index is equal to 0 then item will be the first node
     */


    public void add(int index, Student item) {
        if(index < 0 || index > size){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        if(index ==0){
            addFirst(item);
        }
        Node<Student> temp = head;
        for(int i= 0; i < index-1; i++){
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = new Node<Student>(item,temp.next);
        size++;


    }

    /**
     * Append the specified item to the end of the list
     * @param item The item to be appended
     * @returns true (as specified by the Collection interface)
     */
    /**
     * if head is null then temp which holds item will be the first node.
     * While temp next node is not equal to null temp is equal to the next node
     * When it is equal to null the while loop will stop and a new node is created 
     * and added to the end of the list
     * @param item
     * @return 
     */
    public boolean add(Student item) {
        Student temp = item;
        if(head == null){
            addFirst(temp);
            return true;
        }
        Node<Student> temp2 = head;
        while(temp2.next != null){
            temp2 = temp2.next;
        }
        temp2.next = new Node<Student>(temp);
        size++;
        return true;


    }
        int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Obtain a string representation of the list
     * @return A String representation of the list 
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
        Node p = head;
        if (p != null) {
            while (p.next != null) {
                sb.append(p.data.toString());
                sb.append(" ==> ");
                p = p.next;
            }
            sb.append(p.data.toString());
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Remove the first occurence of element item.
     * @param item The item to be removed
     * @return true if item is found and removed; otherwise, return false.
     */
    public boolean remove(Student item) {
        if (head == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Node<Student> current = head;
        if (item.equals(current.data)) {
            removeFirst();
            return true;
        }
        while (current.next != null) {
            if (item.equals(current.next.data)) {
                removeAfter(current);
                return true;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Nested Class
    /** A Node is the building block for the SingleLinkedList */

}
```

Comment: Share your stack trace

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted more of your code, particularly the code for the Node class. It would also be helpful if you posted the full text of the error message (I assume this is an error message from the compiler?).

Comment: @bart.s I am afraid I dont know how to do that

Comment: @Chris I believe bart is just asking for more of the available error information.

Comment: I have attached the rest of my LinkedList/Node class code

Comment: `private static class Node<Student> ` - You do not need a type parameter here (since `data` will always be of type `Student`).

Comment: @Chris what I see now is that you are trying to access Node's private variable data, which might cause an error, but we need more detailed error from your compiler

Answer (score 0):

```
private static class Node<Student> {
```

This is equivalent to the more traditional

```
private static class Node<T> {
```

It declares a generic Node class, with a type parameter T, which can be any type. So

```
private Student data;
```

Actually declares a field of a generic type, which could be anything.

You probably want the Node and LinkedList class to not be generic at all, since it's only supposed to contain students, or to be declared as

```
private static class Node<T extends Student> {
```

Comment: When I change the header to <T extends Student> it fixes the issue but breaks everything else

Comment: It's not just the header that you should change. Again, you probably don't want the classes to be generic, so you should just declare them as `private static class Node` and `public class StudentSingleLinkedList`.

Comment: So that worked and got rid of the errors but I guess I am not fully understanding to why that is the correct way? any insight?

Comment: A generic class, like the built-in LinkedList, allows containing objects of any type. So if you create a LinkedList<String>, it can only contain String, and if you create a LinkedList<Student>, it can only contain Student. But of course, since it can contain anything, the LinkedList can't make any assumption on what it contains, and ut thus can't call any method of Student, since it could in fact containStrings, Cars or Bananas. Your class can only contain Students; it internally calls Student methods on the items it holds. So it can't be generic: the only thing it can contain is Students.

Comment: If you want to make it generic, then you can't have methods like `findGpa` in the list, which only make sense for Students, and not for anything else, thus making the code non-generic at all.